# What is the different between $HasTextChildren and $HasVNodeChildren plus createTextVNode()?

Tags: javascript, infernojs

In Inferno, when trying to define children shape in compile time, there are two ways for defining the children as text:

```
function Hello() {
  let h = "Hello";
  return (
    <p $HasTextChildren>
      {h}
    </p>
  );
}
```

```
import { createTextVNode } from "inferno";

function Hello() {
  let h = "Hello";
  return (
    <p $HasVNodeChildren>
      {createTextVNode(h)}
    </p>
  );
}
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the end result, there is no difference. However, performance-wise, the former is a bit faster. But the limitation is that the children must be text only. There might be cases when you want to have text *and* other stuff as children. In that case, you can use `createTextVNode()` and one the appropriate flags, one of them being `$HasVNodeChildren`. You can see a list of flags in the docs: https://www.infernojs.org/docs/guides/optimizations

As an additional note, you don't have to define children shape yourself if the compiler can see it at compile time. So instead of this:

```
function Hello() {
  return <p $HasTextChildren>Hello</p>;
}
```

You can simply write:

```
function Hello() {
  return <p>Hello</p>;
}
```